# How to exclude class from being initialized in tests

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spock

I'm using mysql and elastic in my project. There are two base classes to set up docker needed for unit tests.

Tests classes structure

```
    BaseDBTest
    - ExampleDBTest
    -....
    BaseElasticTest
     - ExampleElasticTest
     -....
```

Static blocks to configure containers that look like (elastic one is pretty much the same, just with different naming/docker image).

```
    static {
        MYSQL_CONTAINER = createContainer() //set up params/passwords etc.
        MYSQL_CONTAINER.start();
    }
```

Static blocks are needed because I have to use `@DynamicPropertySource` which requires static method.

For now elastic is no longer supported, though it might be, so I don't want to delete all elastic tests.
Instead, I wonder whether it's possible not to initialize them. I know that I can use `@Ignore` to ignore tests, but the static block in `BaseElasticTest` would still be called. That causes some issues in CICD as sometimes it takes too long and fails build.
I've tried setting up different `@ActiveProfile` / `@IfProfileValue` / `@EnabledIf` etc. but even if tests are not run - the static method is still called.

Any idea how to stop the initialization of any class that matches the name `..ElasticTest` or have custom annotation?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `static` blocks, use testcontainers with [jdbc support](https://java.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/jdbc/) for a seamless integration.